# PHP $_COOKIE returns null BUT Chrome shows cookie with correct value

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Im trying to set custom cookies in wordpress without success, so i thought it might be because of the cache and set up a small test on my localhost apache and have the same problem.

In Chrome the cookies "chat_guest" and "chat_guest_hash" are visible but when trying to get their value it returns "null" .

In the example code I use var_dump to see if their is any cookie with value but it returns `array(0) { }` and still, the cookies are shown in Chrome!

```
<?php



if(!isset($_COOKIE['chat_guest'])) {
    if (!setcookie('chat_guest', "test1", 365 * 3000, "/")) die("?? 1");
    if (!setcookie('chat_guest_hash', "test", 365 * 3000, "/")) die("?? 2");
}

echo var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

I just cant get behind this. Any ideas?

Comment: You did keep in mind that cookies only show up in $_COOKIE after the browser has send them back with the next request, and _not_ directly in the same request where you tried to set them - right …?

Comment: When I refresh the page the problems is still there

Comment: The `expires` parameter needs to be a unix timestamp, not a number of seconds it should be valid for. You made your cookie valid until Tue, 13 Jan 1970 17:10:00 +0100 - so no wonder it doesn’t get send back to the server by the browser “any more” …

Comment: yes and no to be more preciese @misorude "The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). `time()+60*60*24*30` will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).  source the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the global $_COOKIE tag like you are doing - just like the $_SESSION or $_SERVER... Although you cant set the cookie like that.
Here is the right way where the cookie is stored in ~one month:

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["chat_guest"])){ //checks if the cookie "chat_guest exists
       setcookie("chat_guest", "test1", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
      //setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    }

   print_r($_COOKIE); // prints all data stored within the super global $_COOKIE
```

Remember to refresh your browser when working with cookies like that

Answer (score 1):

The cookie isn't set until the response is sent back to the client and isn't available in your PHP until the next request from the client after that.

If you want immediate access, you can set $_COOKIE['chat_guest'] manually:

```php
setcookie('chat_guest', "test1", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
$_COOKIE['chat_guest'] = "test1";
```

Comment: This sets the expire also **wrong** so not sure why this is upvoted.  "you'll most likely set this with the `time()` function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire" source the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeap, I didn't noticed the expire time and the double ; in the end. My mistake.

Comment: tried to edit it - but i dont have enough reputation - please edit the expire to time() + (86400 * 30)